# How to communicate the JDBC Driver with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jdbc, derby

How can I connect to a Derby database using JDBC in ASP.NET MVC?

1. I have searched about that, but the main problem is about how to use JDBC with ASP.NET since ASP.NET MVC has ADO and Java has JDBC.
2. How should I use ASP.NET JDBC? ADO or JDBC or ?

I'm here to know the path that I need to go, to learn and understand the concept that I should use to write this code.

Comment: My understanding is that JDBC is an API that may only be used directly from the Java language. In order to connect to Derby from .Net you'll need to use a .Net compliant API like ODBC or ADO. I suggest you try this ODBC driver: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0409cline2/

Comment: Thank you. I will study ODBC and that driver!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid JDBC can be used from all languages running on the JVM, not just from Java.

Comment: You might want to look at https://sourceforge.net/projects/derbynet/

Comment: Thank you MarkRotteveel but this just read the data and I need a CRUD. And @Nick.McDermaid that driver was discontinued. I'm back to the first point.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @MarkRotteveel - that makes more sense. What other languages can be compiled to run inside a JVM?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Scala, groovy, python (Jython), clojure, kotlin to name a few (there are more).

Comment: Well, then you are probably out of luck. Use a different database, or switch to Java. Maybe you can get away with using what is suggested here: http://codemesh.com/products/juggernet/examples/jdbc.html